# How to add IP to EC2 firewall

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lamp

We run a number of different servers that are hosted in a local data centre however our Dev server is hosted on AWS and I'm having trouble accessing it.

The EC2 server is running a LAMP stack, I can FTP to the server and get any files I need but when I try and access the webmin at port 10000 I get an access denied message for my IP.

I assume this is because the IP is being blocked by the firewall, however I need to be able to access PHPMyAdmin on this server to pull some database files down. I can access the AWS console but I don't know where to alter the firewall details.

Comment: What research have you done on this on your own before coming here?

Comment: I've searched extensively through Stack Overflow and Server Fault, I've asked the previous server admin who didn't seem to know how to change it and I've spent about two hours reading through AWS documentation.

Comment: @JamiePatt This link is the second result in Google for "aws firewall", and I'd suggest you read it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: *"I get an access denied message for my IP. I assume this is because the IP is being blocked by the firewall"*  If you think about it for just a minute, you should realize that this is highly unlikely.  If you were being blocked by a firewall, you wouldn't get far enough to see an "access denied" message.

Comment: Like @Michael-sqlbot said, it sounds like you're getting an actual error message.  Can you post the exact error message?  A Firewall/AWS security group issue would mean you can't even connect to that ip:port.

Comment: The error message is Error - Access Denied for (my ip address)

Comment: Update your webmin  allow access.  
http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Securing_Webmin

Comment: Although what you ask may NOT be  secure way to meet your real objective. To securely pull data from phpmyadmin, you can easily use ssh tunneling, make use of the ssh connection already allow in your EC2 security group.

Answer (score 2):

Check the security group attached with your instance. Go ahead with adding rule like 'protocol:tcp' 'port 10000' in "Inbound traffic" allowing only from your IP using 'MyIP' or from 'anywhere'. Verify it with $telnet 'ec2-ip' 10000

Comment: Thanks for this, adding my IP to the security group hasn't helped so I'm going through the AWS Support. I'll leave this question up though for people who have a similar problem.

Comment: You may have to check 'IP Access Control' and 'Ports and Addresses' in webmin configuration. I suspect restrictions in access control or bind address could be a loopback one. [link](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Configuration).
To change in CLI: /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf and restart webmin.

If that didn't fix and if you're using Centos, try disabling Selinux using the command #setenforce 0

Answer (score 0):

It could be the EC2 security groups, which act as a firewall. I've written an article which shows people [how to add CloudFlare IP addresses to the AWS security group](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-6-setting-up-cloudflare-caching-security/), but it will show you the principles of how to modify the security groups so it's worth a read.

In short:

1. Log into EC2 console Find your instance, click on the security group
   link, which takes you to the group
2. Hit edit on the security group
3. Add whatever ports you want to whatever IP addresses you want, using CIDR notation. In this notation 0.0.0.0/0 means "everyone can access
   this protocol/port".
4. Hit save

Comment: Thanks for this, adding my IP to the security group hasn't helped so I'm going through the AWS Support. I'll leave this question up though for people who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the miniserv.conf file to allow access from that IP and restarting webmin.